# Insert Collection to saveMany Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a Collection filled with Models, how would I put these into the `saveMany` method on a relation? I know it must be an array, but when I do `$collection->toArray()` they are no Eloquent models anymore.

```
public function uploadAndGetModels($messageId, array $attachments)
{
    $models = new Collection();
    $attachments = new Collection($attachments);
    $attachments->each(function (UploadedFile $attachment) use ($messageId, $models) {
        $identifier = $this->uploader->makeIdentifier($attachment->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $this->uploader->uploadImage($attachment, "attachments/{$identifier}");
        $model = new Attachment(array('message_id' => $messageId, 'path' => $identifier));
        $models->push($model);
    });

    return $models;
}
```

The result of `$models` is a `Collection` full of `Attachment` models.

```
if ($request->hasFile('attachments')) {
    $attachments = $attachmentRepository->uploadAndGetModels($message->id, $request->file('attachments'));
    $message->attachments()->saveMany($attachments);
}
```

How would I be able to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Collection` class has an `all()` method which returns all the items in the collection as an array of models.

With that in mind, this should work...

```
$message->attachments()->saveMany($attachments->all());
```